# How can I make xml.sax use a HTTP proxy for its DTD requests?

Tags: python, xml, sax

It is a known problem that [XML parsers often send out HTTP requests for fetching DTDs](http://www.w3.org/blog/systeam/2008/02/08/w3c_s_excessive_dtd_traffic) referenced in the documents. Specifically, [Python's one does this](http://bugs.python.org/issue2124). This causes excessive traffic for www.w3.org, which hosts a lot of these DTDs. In turn, this makes the XML parsing take a very long time and in some cases time out. This can be a serious problem, as it makes a task seemingly only related to text processing dependent on an unreliable third party.

In order to mitigate this problem (since a real solution is very hard), I'd like to install a caching web proxy locally and ask xml.sax to send its requests via this proxy. I specifically don't want the proxy settings leaking out to other components, so system wide settings are out of the question.

How can I make xml.sax use a HTTP proxy?

I've got:

```
handler = # instance of a subclass of xml.sax.handler.ContentHandler

parser = xml.sax.make_parser()
parser.setContentHandler(handler)
parser.parse(indata)
return handler.result()
```

---

One approach is to use a custom EntityResolver. However, it turns out [it is not possible to implement a caching EntityResolver](http://bugs.python.org/msg81080), because it doesn't get enough information.

Comment: @aaronasterling: 2.5 preferred, but 2.6 and 2.7 are acceptable as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One quick and dirty way to do this would be to monkey patch `saxutils.prepare_input_source`. You can pretty much just copy+paste it and tweak the branch that calls `urllib.urlopen` so that it gets a `UrlOpener` from `urllib2` with your proxy installed.

Unfortunately, I think that this is the only way that you're going to be able to get your literally desired behavior without changing system wide settings or creating your own `EntityResolver` that could cache results.

The problem is that `saxutils.prepare_input_source` pretty unambiguously makes a call to `urllib.urlopen` and with no options for modifying this behavior. So you'd have to route that through your proxy which would affect all other clients of `urllib`.

---

*By Magnus Hoff:* A working monkey-patching implementation:

```
def make_caching_prepare_input_source(old_prepare_input_source, proxy):
    def caching_prepare_input_source(source, base = None):
        if isinstance(source, xmlreader.InputSource):
            return source

        full_uri = urlparse.urljoin(base or "", source)

        if not full_uri.startswith('http:'):
            args = (source,) if base == None else (source, base)
            return old_prepare_input_source(*args)

        r = urllib2.Request(full_uri)
        r.set_proxy(proxy, 'http')
        f = urllib2.urlopen(r)

        i = xmlreader.InputSource()
        i.setSystemId(source)
        i.setByteStream(f)

        return i

    return caching_prepare_input_source

def enable_http_proxy(server):
    saxutils.prepare_input_source = make_caching_prepare_input_source(
        saxutils.prepare_input_source,
        server,
    )
```

Comment: Hmm... Are you sure? In python 2.5.1 entities are resolved deep inside in `expat.c`, and `urlopen` is called just for the source.

Comment: @khachik. Yes, but getting the source is the whole issue. If that could be cached (by being routed through a proxy), then the objective would be achieved. Or am I missing something?

Comment: I'm working on an EntityResolver now, so any insights in that direction are welcome as well :) Apparently, I don't get the `base` argument that's included for `saxutils.prepare_input_source`.

Comment: @aaronasterling I think - no. Source is got well, since it tries to fetch entities came from the source.

Comment: @Magnus according to http://bugs.python.org/msg81080 it won't help, but you should try, of course. BTW, another approach is to use xml parsers that support XML catalogs.

Comment: @Magnus your question is really good, i would up-vote it once more if I can

Comment: @Magnus, Looks good on the whole. The one question I have is about when you overwrite `source` and then pass it to the old function if it doesn't start with `http`. Would it be better to send the result of `urljoin` to a temporary variable and check that so that the original `source` is still available to send to the old function? It's sleeping time here but If I'm motivated tomorrow, I'll get the `EntityResolver` working. It can definitely be done by subclassing `ExpatParser`

Comment: @aaronasterling: Done. It'd still be interesting to see an EntityResolver-based implementation. :)